# How do I disable form submit with enter key?

Tags: javascript

I have a js event on enter keypress which works fine. But after that event it also submits the form which has a submit button. How do I stop that submit button from getting focus after the previous keypress event?

EDIT: I DONT WANT THE SUBMIT BUTTON TO SUBMIT ON ENTER, ONLY ON CLICK.

Comment: Okay, so replace your submit with a button. So instead of <input type="submit".." get an <input type="button".. and attach an onclick event to it. In the onclick handler, do stuff and call the submit() method of the form.

Comment: I feel like this is worth repeating: I strongly discourage this kind of non-standard behavior - unless you have a very good, very specific use case where this functionality just simply *must* be altered. Aside from that, the answers here are correct: your keypress event handler should simply return 'false'.

Comment: @anonymouscoward - many embedded or terminal-like systems do not have tab keys for moving between fields. Users have been conditioned to hit ENTER after typing in data for a field to advance to the next field. I agree that this is non-optimal, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with java script are as follows;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function stopReloadKey(evt) {
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
      var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
      if (evt.keyCode == 13)  {
          return false;
      }
    }

    document.onkeypress = stopReloadKey;

    </script>
```

Or Using Jquery you can do this by,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                 return false;
              }
           });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you are trying to prevent the form from getting submitted:

Attach an onsubmit event and return false from it.

```
<form onsubmit="submit_handler();"></form>
[...]

function submit_handler()
{
    //do stuff
    return (false);
}
```

Comment: WHat about the enter key stuff? He wants it to only submit with mouseclick, not enterkey

Comment: Yeah, I commented on his question.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the answer to javascript questions of the type "How do I keep my form from submitting after I ...." is "make your javascript function return `false`".

Comment: This will work. Although I strongly discourage non-standard behavior - unless you have a very good, very specific use case where this functionality just simply *must* be altered.

Answer (score 0):

any enter fires the submit event
you need to override it - here a short example code (5 lines) how to do it
http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx